# Plotting multiple scatter plots pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I think there are many questions on plotting multiple graphs but not specifically for this case as shown below.

The pandas documentation says to 'repeat plot method' to plot multiple column groups in a single axes. However, how would this work for 3 or more column groups? For example if we define a third column:

```
bx = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='a',y='f',color = 'Green',label ='f')
```

Where would this bx be passed into?

Also, if the plot is the same graph, shouldn't the x-axis be consistently either 'a' or 'c'? but the documentation has 2 different x axis: 'a' **and** 'c'

[image]

Comment: Could you please add sample data/ initialize a dataframe in your question?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Where would this bx be passed into?

You ought to repeat the second call to `plot`, not the first, so there is no need for `bx`.

In detail: `plot` takes an optional `ax` argument. This is the axes it draws into. If the argument is not provided the function creates a new plot and axes. In addition, the axes is returned by the function so it can be reused for further drawing operations. The idea is *not* to pass an `ax` argument to the first call to `plot` and use the returned axes in all subsequent calls.

You can verify that each call to plot returns the same axes that it got passed:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 6), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])


ax1 = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='a', y='b', color='r')    
ax2 = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='c', y='d', color='g', ax=ax1)    
ax3 = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='e', y='f', color='b', ax=ax1)

print(ax1 == ax2 == ax3)  # True
```

[image]

> Also, if the plot is the same graph, shouldn't the x-axis be consistently either 'a' or 'c'?

Not necessarily. If it makes sense to put different columns on the same axes depends on what data they represent. For example, if `a` was income and `c` was expenditures it would make sense to put both on the same 'money' axis. In contrast, if `a` was number of peas and `c` was voltage they should probably not be on the same axis.

Comment: It is so silly that `df.plot(kind='line')` only requires a single call to plot all three lines, whilst `df.plot(kind='scatter')` require three calls. Points to underlying bad design of the library imho.

Comment: This is perfect, for anyone needing it: use the label='' parameter to appropriately label your markers.

Comment: does anyone knows how to achieve this using `plotly.express`

Answer (score 18):

You can plot any column against any column you like. Whether that makes sense you have to decide for yourself. E.g. plotting a column denoting time on the same axis as a column denoting distance may not make sense, but plotting two columns which both contain distance on the same axis, is fine.

In order to specify that a certin plot should be on an already existing axes (`ax`), you'd specify the `ax` keyword as seen in the documentation. Of couse you can create several plots on the same axes.

```
ax = df.plot(kind="scatter", x="x",y="a", color="b", label="a vs. x")
df.plot(x="x",y="b", color="r", label="b vs. x", ax=ax)
df.plot( x="x",y="c", color="g", label="c vs. x", ax=ax)
```

A complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,6.3, 50)
a = (np.sin(x)+1)*3
b = (np.cos(x)+1)*3
c = np.ones_like(x)*3
d = np.exp(x)/100.
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":x, "a":a, "b":b, "c":c, "d":d})

ax = df.plot(kind="scatter", x="x",y="a", color="b", label="a vs. x")
df.plot(x="x",y="b", color="r", label="b vs. x", ax=ax)
df.plot( x="x",y="c", color="g", label="c vs. x", ax=ax)
df.plot( x="d",y="x", color="orange", label="b vs. d", ax=ax)
df.plot( x="a",y="x", color="purple", label="x vs. a", ax=ax)

ax.set_xlabel("horizontal label")
ax.set_ylabel("vertical label")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Inside the [holoviz](https://holoviz.org) ecosystem, there is a library called [`hvplot`](https://hvplot.pyviz.org/) which provides very nice high-level plotting functionality (on top of [`holoviews`](https://holoviews.org)) that works out of the box with Pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import hvplot.pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 6), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])

df.hvplot(x='a', y=['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], kind='scatter')
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This has become an easy oneliner in pandas if you choose a different plotting backend, for example plotly instead of matplotlib, using argument `backend=plotly`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 6), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])

# notice argument backend='plotly' to change the plotting backend of pandas
df.plot(
    kind='scatter',
    x='a', 
    y=['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
    backend='plotly', 
    width=500,   
)
```

Resulting plot:

[image: different plotting backend makes multiple scatter plots easy]

Comment: before using `backend='plotly'` as an argument, one must do `pip install plotly hvplot` to install `plotly` and `hvplot` packages.

Answer (score 1):

You could plot the multiple columns automatically within a for loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 5), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',])

f,ax = plt.subplots(1)

for x,y,c in zip(['a','c','e'],['b','d','d'],['r','g','b']):
    df.plot(kind='scatter', 
            x=x, 
            y=y, 
            color=c, 
            ax=ax, 
            label='{} vs {}'.format(x,y)
            )
```

Then, of course, the columns of the dataframe and the colors can also be generated from code instead of hard coded.