# In Pandas how do i plot for one group only?

Tags: python, pandas

What I want to do is to apply the plot function only to certain selection of records in a dataset. Let's say, I have a column of length (numeric), a column of body mass (numeric) and a column of sex (Male or Female). I want to scatterplot the length vs the mass, but only for Male, so that Female won't appear on the plot. How do I do that?

Comment: `df[df['sex']=='Male'].plot.scatter(x='length', y='mass')`

Comment: @QuangHoang correct. I guess we should close/delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to filter your dataframe to provide information only for the rows for which `sex` is `Male`. This will be the input for your plot.

```
df_1 = df.loc[df['sex'].eq('Male')]
```

Once you have done the filtering, you need to add the plotting syntax which is as @Quang Hoang commented `.plot.scatter(x='length',y='mass')` which will be the values for your `x` and `y` axis. In a single line:

```
df_1 = df.loc[df['sex'].eq('Male')].plot.scatter(x='length',y='mass')
```

EDIT: If there were more columns in your dataframe and you wish to only keep those two (length and mass) then your filtering should be done with:

```
df_1 = df.loc[df['sex'].eq('Male'),['length','mass']]
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation. what if there is more than two columns like Length, Mass, Height, Weight etc?

Comment: I will edit my answer in second to example that case. However if there were to be more it shouldn't be any issue with the code provided. Edit done.

Comment: maybe i was not clear what i was asking is what if i want to plot more than two columns for male. i am sorry i am just learning this.

Comment: For multiple columns you should make multiple plots (because of scatterplots being 2D), here is a question that adresses your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061768/plotting-multiple-scatter-plots-pandas .